# Use JavaScript to get SharePoint task associated with item without using Related Items

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a bit of an unusual environment, where the client does not want to support SharePoint components, and as such I have an O365 SharePoint site that I can only do things programmatically through workflows or JavaScript.

I have workflows that are starting tasks, except for some reason I occasionally get a task that does not get the "Related Items" populated.  Because of this, my lookup to find the items with a task associated with them failed, because I was looking for the Related Item to be the ID I was working with.  I can still follow from the list item, to the workflow, to the task.  Is there another way, using something like WorkflowItemId, that I can associate the tasks to these items?

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code I have to find the tasks by a item Id, it either deletes the tasks (when the list item is deleted), or populates taskId to display in a form, this is used in O365 SharePoint online. Give it the ID of the list item, and change the list title to your task list title. Let me know if any other questions.

```
     $.fn.get_taskIds = function (param) {
     var itemTitle, taskId, curID = param.ItemId, foundAction = param.action;
     get_listData(appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ExpirationTaskList')/items?$select=RelatedItems,Id,Title").done(
        function (data) {
            var itemJSON;
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                itemJSON = $.parseJSON(item.RelatedItems);
                itemTitle = item.Title;
                taskId = item.Id;
                $(itemJSON).each(function (i, val) {
                    $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                        if (k == 'ItemId') {
                            if (v == curID) {
                                switch (foundAction) {
                                    case 'view':
                                        if (itemTitle == 'Warranty Expiration') { $('#WTaskId').val(taskId); $('#wTaskRadio').attr('disabled', false); }
                                        if (itemTitle == 'Lease Expiration') { $('#LTaskId').val(taskId); $('#lTaskRadio').attr('disabled', false); }
                                        break;
                                    case 'delete':
                                        delete_Task(taskId);
                                        break;
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
            });

        }).fail(function (arg) {
            $('#jsError').html('Fail in Async Query to Retrieve task data: <br />');
            var jsonResp = $.parseJSON(arg.responseText);
            $('#jsError').append(jsonResp.error.message.value);
        });
}
```

function get_listData(aurl) {

```
    var dfrd = $.Deferred(function (dfrd) {
        $.ajax({
            url: aurl,
            type: "Get",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                dfrd.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (args) {
                dfrd.reject(args);
            }
        });
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```